# Visual Basic 2010 connecting to my database

Tags: database-connection, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

Private Sub OK_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click

```
    If TextBox1.Text = "1234" Then



        ' This is the connection. You have to have this exact string, except "E:\Documents\notekeeper.mdb" will be the path to your thing instead

        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=N:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Maths System Aid\Maths System Aid\Database7.mdb;User=;Password=;")
        Try
            conn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Cannot open database")
        End Try



        ' The SQL statement / command

        Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand("Insert INTO Student ([First Name], [Surname], [Username], [Password]) VALUES "("" & TextBox5.Text & "," & TextBox4.Text & "," & TextBox3.Text & "," & TextBox2.Text & "" & ")"), conn)







        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ' Use ExecuteReader() to execute SELECT statements, but ExecuteNonQuery() for others






        ' Basically, the reader is like an array of all of the records that have been returned by the database


        Me.Close()
        StudentLogin.Show()

    Else
        MsgBox("Enter The Correct Confirmation code")

    End If
End Sub
```

my problem is that it will not find my database file. I have followed the path and it is correct. Any ideas of what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this in quite some time but at the top of your form you should be running some imports firstly

```
                                        imports system.data
```

Then you should define rather like this:

```
                                dim conn as new oledb.oledbconnection
```

Another issue I noticed in your code is that you're using the Jet provider which if memory serves correctly only works with the new databases using the .accdb extension. Try to change it to an accdb in access.. I'll go over it quick and see what I can conjure up. Hopefully that helps at least. The alternative provider if you run into issues :

```
                                ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.......
```

Comment: Also, it would help a lot if in your try catch block you run messagebox.show(ex.tostring) that will give you a detailed error

Comment: thank you, i do have the code imports system.data it's just that it is right at the top and I forgot to paste it in.

Comment: No problem. Let me know how those solutions work out for you. If you're still having trouble, post the exception message printed out in the messagebox. Your code looks fine besides maybe swapping your ACE or Jet provider. Another notation is that if there is no username or password you can end the connection statement before ;username..

Comment: I see what you mean by that, the problem seems to be with the connection. It doesn't seem to be finding the database through the path. I have chekced multiple times the path I have put but to no avail.

Comment: Could be something as silly as forward slashes as opposed to backward slashes. Toy around and move it to a different directory. If that doesn't work, you can import the data source with vb's database wizard (not ideal) but it will work

Comment: Just as a note @Neal, Jet is more than happy to connect to the older mdb

Comment: Yes. ACE is for accdb extensions and Jet is for the mbd extension. I just hadn't done it for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this path a local disk or a network disk? is it on another computer or a mapped network drive?

The way I connect is

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dbProvider As String
Dim dbSource As String

dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
dbSource = "Data Source = C:\data\database.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=******;"
con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
con.open()
con.close()
```

This should work perfect but use your path and password if you have one